# $.ajax send twice, event.preventDefault not usable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I just learning javascript and jquery now I have a problem using jquery datatables.

My Data were post twice to php. I don´t know how to implement event.preventDefault on my script and return false wont work.

```
olistorderproduktdatatable = $("#listorderprodukttable").dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true, "bPaginate": false, "bFilter": true, "bInfo": false, "bAutoWidth": true, "sDom": 'Rlfrtip', 
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sSearch" :"Filter",
    "bDestroy": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "share/content/helper/datatablelistorderprodukt.php" 
});

$('#listorderprodukttable tbody').delegate("tr", "click", rowClickAddPosition);

function rowClickAddPosition(){
    //Welche Zeile wurde selektiert und ID herausfiltern 
   if (hlr)
      $("td:first", hlr).parent().children().each(function(){$(this).removeClass('markrow');});
   hlr = this;
   $("td:first", this).parent().children().each(function(){$(this).addClass('markrow');});

   // You can pull the values out of the row here if required
   var a = $("td:first", this).text();
   var b = $("td:eq(1)", this).text();

   selectedRow      = a;  //ID der Zeile WICHTIGE VARIABLE!!!

    //Abfrage ob ID leer ist, also ob es überhaupt Einträge gibt.
   if(selectedRow != "No matching records found"){
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'share/content/helper/orderaddposition.php',
            cache: false,
            data: {
                SelectedProdukt : selectedRow,
                BestellID       : BestellID
            },
            success: function(data) {
                callbackaddposition();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I don´t know how to catch the event?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
function rowClickAddPosition(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) and use `return false` in function like,

```
$('#listorderprodukttable tbody').delegate("tr", "click", function(e){
    rowClickAddPosition(e);
    return false;// to stop bubbling up
});

function rowClickAddPosition(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   // remaining code
```

Comment: When I implement this, my logic to analyse the clicked row wont work. selectedRow is empty.

Comment: I have now implement it as follow:

    if(!ajaxLoading) {
                ajaxLoading = true;   
                $.ajax({
           type : 'POST',
           url : 'share/content/helper/orderaddposition.php',
           cache: false,
           data: {
            SelectedProdukt : selectedRow,
            BestellID       : BestellID
           },
           success: function(data) {
                           ajaxLoading = false;
                                    callbackaddposition();
                                    
                    }
          });
            }